# Using the this keyword with jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

Can someone please help me with the `syntax` of using the `jQuery` `this` keyword?

Here is my code that works:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

$('.example_infobox1').addClass(obj.gridlayout);
$('.example_infobox1 .info-box').addClass(obj.boxcolor);    
$('.example_infobox1 .info-box-icon').addClass(obj.iconcolor);
$('.example_infobox1 i').addClass(obj.icon);
$('.example_infobox1 .info-box-text').html(obj.text);
$('.example_infobox1 .info-box-number').html(obj.number);
```

Here is the code that I am working on:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

$('.example_infobox1')
{
    $(this).addClass(obj.gridlayout);
    $('.info-box', this).addClass(obj.boxcolor);    
    $('.info-box-icon', this).addClass(obj.iconcolor);
    $('i', this).addClass(obj.icon);
    $('.info-box-text', this).html(obj.text);
    $('.info-box-number', this).html(obj.number);
}
```

I am not getting any errors in the console, however the html content is not being correctly formatted.

Thanks

Comment: please post ur html as well

Comment: I'd suggest you look at [jQuery's `.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/).  That's what you want if you want to do a selector search only in a sub-tree.  `this` is not involved in this type of activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a variable would be better in this case.

```
var box = $('.example_infobox1');

box.addClass(obj.gridlayout);
$('.info-box', box).addClass(obj.boxcolor);    
$('.info-box-icon', box).addClass(obj.iconcolor);
$('i', box).addClass(obj.icon);
$('.info-box-text', box).html(obj.text);
$('.info-box-number', box).html(obj.number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that is the wrong usage of jQuery selector.

jQuery assignes current document object to `this` within this "selector".

http://jsfiddle.net/8rLdwr5w/1/
Take a look at this sample. Here the jQuery object contains the whole document and I can access external `div` using `find` method.

If you want the jQuery selection to be called once and then reused, follow Stuart Wagner's approach.

Answer (score 0):

this points to current object in jquery and it gives an error only when syntax is wrong.
your should try this.

$(this).find('.info-box').addClass(obj.boxcolor);
or 
$('.example_infobox1 > div[class = ".info-box"]').addClass(obj.boxcolor);

or

$(".example_infobox1 ").children(".info-box").addClass( "obj.boxcolor");